# Using LaunchedEffect with data class field as key

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm using jetpack compose, and I have a screen that is represented as a sealed class, and it can be one of three possible values: Loading, Error and DataLoaded. Now DataLoaded is a data class with multiple fields, and I have a LaunchedEffect block and I want to run some logic ONLY when a particular field changes. I have tried using the field itself as the key to the LaunchedEffect block, but the block runs when any field changes and I believe that's expected but I would like to know if there's a way around this or if I have to change my structure. Here my VM that serves the serves my ui with a state flow.

```
class NowPlayingViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val audioRepository: AudioRepository,
) : ViewModel() {
    private val errorFlow = MutableStateFlow<PlaybackException?>(null)
    private val progressFlow = MutableStateFlow(0L)
    private val playbackStateFlow = MutableStateFlow(-1)
    private val nowPlayingFlow = audioRepository.getNowPlayingFlow()
    val uiState =
        combine(
            nowPlayingFlow,
            progressFlow,
            playbackStateFlow,
            errorFlow
        ) { nowPlaying, progress, playbackState, exception ->
            when {
                nowPlaying != null -> {
                    NowPlayingState.TrackLoaded(
                        nowPlaying.track,
                        nowPlaying.isPlaying,
                        nowPlaying.repeatMode,
                        nowPlaying.shuffleActive,
                        progress,
                        playbackState
                    )
                }

                exception != null -> {
                    val errorMessage = exception.localizedMessage ?: ""
                    NowPlayingState.ErrorLoadingTrack(Result.Error(errorMessage))
                }

                else -> null
            }
        }.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000), initialValue = null)
}
```

And my composable like so:

```
@Composable
fun NowPlayingScreen(
    uiState: NowPlayingState.TrackLoaded,
    nowPlayingViewModel: NowPlayingViewModel,
    goBack: () -> Unit
) {
    val (track, isPlaying, repeatMode, isShuffleActive, progress, playbackState) = uiState
  
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = track) {
        Timber.d("LAUNCHED EFFECT")
    }
}
```

Also here is what the Track class looks like:

```
@Entity
data class Track(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    val trackId: Long,
    val trackTitle: String,
    val trackLength: Int,
    val artist: String,
    val albumId: Long,
    val contentUri: Uri?,
    val thumbnail: Bitmap? = null,
    val mimeType: String?,
    val hasThumbnail: Boolean
)
```

How can I make my LaunchedEffect block run only when only the current track changes? Right now it runs when any of the uiState fields change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess that it might be because of `Bitmap` at Track class. While it looks like correct code we don't see how you generate the `Track` at `AudioRepository`, maybe it fetches the bitmap on every data changes regarding to this repository like `repeatMode`. Whether this is problem or not, I suggest considering passing  `uiState.track.trackId` to `LaunchedEffect`, since it has enough information to distinguish between tracks.

Answer (score 0):

Without having tried it out myself tbh, I'd guess that the destructuring in

`val (track, isPlaying, repeatMode, isShuffleActive, progress, playbackState) = uiState`

is to blame. It will always trigger whenever `uiState` changes.

Have you tried using `LaunchedEffect(uiState.track)`?

Comment: yes I have. that was how I initially wrote the code